# .htaccess 301 redirect for just few urls : non www to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hi Please read my question it is different

I have website that work with www and non www versions. now i want to redirect just few say 1,2 url from whole site from non www to www version while rest should work fine in both www and non www mode

For get **http://example.com/test.html** should be redirected to **http://www.example/test.html**

while all other url should work in www and non www modes

I thought of using below code that does not works , need help with same

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule test.html http://www.example.com/test.html [L]
```

Comment: what is the status of this question? If an answer solved it, it should be accepted in order to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect any request for `example.com/test.html` without `www` only try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^test.html  http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

So , any request start `^` with `test.html` will be redirected .

If any request without `www` and ends `$` with `test.html` try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule test.html$  http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

If that code is ok , change `302` to `301` for permanent redirection.

**Note:** clear your browser cache then test the code above